# How to multiply the previous value of an other column with the value of x column (shift)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

I have the following pandas df which consists of 2 factor-columns and 2 signal-columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [0.1,-0.1,0.1],
    [-0.1,0.2,0.3],
    [0.3,0.1,0.3],
    [0.1,0.3,-0.2]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['factor_A', 'factor_B', 'factor_C'])

for col in df:
    new_name = col + '_signal'
    df[new_name] = [1 if x>0 else -1 for x in df[col]]

print(df)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
 factor_A  factor_B  factor_C  factor_A_signal  factor_B_signal  factor_C_signal
0       0.1      -0.1       0.1                1               -1                1
1      -0.1       0.2       0.3               -1                1                1
2       0.3       0.1       0.3                1                1                1
3       0.1       0.3      -0.2                1                1               -1
```

**Now** in a 1 month holding period I have to multiply factor_A with the previous factor_A_signal + factor_B with the previous factor_B_signal divided by the number of factors (in this case "2") and add a new column ("ret_1m). At the moment I am not able to say how much factors I will have as an input so therefore I have to work with a for loop.

In a 2 month holding period I have to multiply the t+1 factor_A with the previous factor_A_signal + the t+1 factor_B with the previous factor_B_signal divided by the number of factors and add a new column ("ret_2m") and so on to the 12th month.

To show you an example I would do that for 2 factors for 3 month holding period as follow:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [0.1,-0.1],
    [-0.1,0.2],
    [0.3,0.1],
    [0.1,0.3]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['factor_A', 'factor_B'])

for col in df:
    new_name = col + '_signal'
    df[new_name] = [1 if x>0 else -1 for x in df[col]]

print(df)


def one_three(n_factors):


    df["ret_1m"] = (df['factor_A_signal'].shift() * df["factor_A"] +
                                        df['factor_B_signal'].shift() * df["factor_B"])/n_factors

    df["ret_2m"] = (df['factor_A_signal'].shift() * df["factor_A"].shift(-1) +
                                        df['factor_B_signal'].shift() * df["factor_B"].shift(-1))/n_factors

    df["ret_3m"] = (df['factor_A_signal'].shift() * df["factor_A"].shift(-2) +
                                        df['factor_B_signal'].shift() * df["factor_B"].shift(-2))/n_factors
    return df

one_three(2)
```

Output:

```
 factor_A  factor_B    factor_A_signal factor_B_signal  ret_1m     ret_2m   ret_3m
0       0.1     -0.1          1               -1          NaN       NaN      NaN
1      -0.1      0.2         -1                1          -0.15     0.1      -0.1
2       0.3      0.1          1                1          -0.10     0.1      NaN
3       0.1      0.3          1                1           0.20     NaN      NaN
```

How could I automate this with a for loop? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop for your function def one_three(n_factors):

```
# Create list of columns in dataframe that are not signals
factors = [x for x in df.columns if not x.endswith("_signal")]
# Looking through range from 1 to 1 + number of months (in your example 3)
for i in range(1, 3+1):
    name = "ret_" + str(i) + "m"
    df[name] = 0
    for x in factors:
        df[name] += df[str(x + "_signal")].shift() * df[x].shift(1 - i)
    df[name] /= len(factors)
```

Assuming you know already populated the factor_ columns, then run the signal loop.  The first section finds all columns that do not end with _signal and returns a list - otherwise you could use a list of `[factor_A, factor_B, ...]`.  Looping through the number of months, here I used 3 following your example, the computation loops through all items in the list.

The output for this matched your output with the given input data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).